# JUnit Test: Unable to unmarshall element

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermockito, opensaml

I have encountered the following difficulty for close to a week now after trying countless solutions across the net. The specific problem relates to `NullPointerException` being thrown after calling the method `Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(Element)` in my JUnit test.

The following is the dependency information for opensaml library imported into my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is the implementation. During normal execution of the program/project, it is able to execute and return the `Response` object successfully.

```
private Response a(String text) throws ConfigurationException, SAXException  {

        DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

        Schema s = SAMLSchemaBuilder.getSAML11Schema();

        BasicParserPool bpp = new BasicParserPool();
        bpp.setNamespaceAware(true);
        bpp.setIgnoreElementContentWhitespace(true);
        bpp.setSchema(schema);

        InputStream is= new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(samlContent).getBytes());
        Response res= null;

        try {
            Document doc = bpp.parse(is);
            Element elmt= doc.getDocumentElement();
            try {

                QName qn = new QName(elmt.getNamespaceURI(), elmt.getLocalName(), elmt.getPrefix());
                Unmarshaller um = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(qn);        <== NullPointerException thrown at this line during JUnit Test**
                samlResponse = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshall(elmt);
            } catch (XMLParserException e) {
                  logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }

        return res;
    }
```

The following is JUnit Test:
(I got a sample samlp:Response string from the following website: https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php)

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(DefaultBootstrap.class);       
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(DefaultBootstrap.class, "bootstrap");


    Response result = classInstance.a(Base64.encode(responseStringFromWebsite));

    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or sharing of knowledge if any of you have encountered similar errors before.

Answer (score 0):

By mocking method DefaultBootstrap # bootstrap, you've skiped initialization of required fields, I guess. Check up the source code of DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(), it will clarify the reason of NPE.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation to help with passing through the following line DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap() in the JUnit without the following mocking method?

Comment: `Field xmlToolingConfigs = Whitebox.getField(DefaultBootstrap.class, "xmlToolingConfigs");
Whitebox.invokeMethod(DefaultBootstrap.class, "initializeXMLTooling", xmlToolingConfigs.get(DefaultBootstrap.class)); `

This code will initialize your unmarshaller, your test must pass (hope so).
Are you sure, that you need mock DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap()?